# Tiempo de ejecución en una petición

Tags: php, nginx

Hola quisiera saber si hay alguna manera realizar una petición al servidor para que realizara un proceso de larga duración, y evitar que cierre la pagina por timeout para luego devolver una respuesta al cliente del proceso realizado, estoy lo estoy realizando con php 5.3

Answer (score 0):

Los procesos de larga duración en el servidor no deben bloquear al usuario.  El timeout sale en el navegador porque el servidor de apache o en el contenedor que corre el php activa el timeout.  revisa por ejemplo cambiar el timeout por defecto que tiene el apache: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/es/mod/core.html#timeout

De todo modos te recomiendo que no uses llamados sincrónicos al servidor,  En cambio de eso ejecuta un llamado asincrónico y muestras otra página que te informa el estado del proceso.  Esta página puede tener un tiempo de refrescado, para que se muestre el cambio del proceso ejecutado en el servidor.

Finalmente puedes implementar WebSockets para que el servidor le avise al navegador cuando esté listo el proceso en el servidor y al cliente le sale una notificación en al página avisando que ya se ejecutó el proceso.

Comment: El petición la estoy realizando mediante ajax, los procesos son muy largos puedes durar horas si no quisiera aumentar el tiempo del servidor la mejor manera seria utilizando WebSockets ???